# How do I take font input from the user in c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Presuming this is windows default font styling dialog, is there any library to enable/call it for user to select the font for the textbox formatting?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "link" it to a textbox?

Comment: If you're using Winforms, add a Font Dialog control to your form.

Comment: As far as your question is concerned of course there is a way to do it. Dont you see it in other applications in day to day life? You already have very correct brilliant answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`FontDialog` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) to display the font dialog to the user.

The [`FontDialog.ShowDialog` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e61ft40c(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration that you can then check to see if the user pressed "OK", and if they did, then you can set the `Font` property of your `TextBox` to the `Font` property of the dialog:

The code below assumes you have a `TextBox` named `textBox1`, and a `Button` named `button1`. Clicking the button allows the user to change the `Font` of `textBox1`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fontDialog = new FontDialog();

    // Show the dialog and check the result. 
    // If the user pressed 'Ok', then change the textbox font
    if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Font = fontDialog.Font;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Assuming you have a FontDialog object (drag and drop from the toolbox) and a textbox, you can add the following code to whatever event you choose. Checking the result of ShowDailog allows to skip the assignment if the user clicks the Cancel button on the dialog.

```
 if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     textBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
 };
```